# flutter inappwebview warning in flutter

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter

i'm implementing a youtube player in my flutter app and when i run it the build will fail and it throws deprication error.

i'm currently using macbook mid 2012, so i can not use latest version of x code. my current version is at Version 12.4 . so in order to use flutter for ios i'm using flutter 2.5.

so now when i try to use youtube player it doesn't build the app.

```
Xcode build done.                                           43.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/mobix/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+2/ios/
    Classes/InAppBrowser/InAppBrowserWebViewController.swift:562:13: warning: setter for 'statusBarStyle'
    was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use -[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]
                UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle(rawValue: previousStatusBarStyle)!
                ^
    /Users/mobix/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+2/ios/
    Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:521:31: warning: 'mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction' was
    deprecated in iOS 9.0
                    configuration.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction =
                    options.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture
                                  ^
    /Users/mobix/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+2/ios/
    Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:932:31: warning: 'mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction' was
    deprecated in iOS 9.0
                    configuration.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction =
                    newOptions.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture
                                  ^
    /Users/mobix/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+2/ios/
    Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebViewOptions.swift:103:81: warning: 'mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction' was
    deprecated in iOS 9.0
                    realOptions["mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture"] =
                    configuration.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction
                                                                                    ^
    /Users/mobix/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+2/ios/
    Classes/MyCookieManager.swift:260:44: error: cannot call value of non-function type 'String?'
                            domain = domainUrl.host()
                                               ^   ~~

    /Users/mobix/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+2/ios/
    Classes/MyCookieManager.swift:294:44: error: cannot call value of non-function type 'String?'
                            domain = domainUrl.host()
                                               ^   ~~

    /Users/mobix/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+2/ios/
    Classes/Types/URLCredential.swift:14:25: warning: comparing non-optional value of type '[Any]' to
    'nil' always returns true
            if certificates != nil {
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~
    /Users/mobix/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+2/ios/
    Classes/Util.swift:216:21: warning: immutable value 'j' was never used; consider replacing with '_'
    or removing it
                    for j in ipv6.count...8 {
                        ^
                        _
    /Users/mobix/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+2/ios/
    Classes/InAppBrowser/InAppBrowserWebViewController.swift:562:13: warning: setter for 'statusBarStyle'
    was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use -[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]
                UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle(rawValue: previousStatusBarStyle)!
                ^
    /Users/mobix/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+2/ios/
    Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:521:31: warning: 'mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction' was
    deprecated in iOS 9.0
                    configuration.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction =
                    options.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture
                                  ^
    /Users/mobix/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+2/ios/
    Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:932:31: warning: 'mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction' was
    deprecated in iOS 9.0
                    configuration.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction =
                    newOptions.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture
                                  ^
    /Users/mobix/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+2/ios/
    Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebViewOptions.swift:103:81: warning: 'mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction' was
    deprecated in iOS 9.0
                    realOptions["mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture"] =
                    configuration.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction
                                                                                    ^
    /Users/mobix/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+2/ios/
    Classes/MyCookieManager.swift:260:44: error: cannot call value of non-function type 'String?'
                            domain = domainUrl.host()
                                               ^   ~~

    /Users/mobix/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+2/ios/
    Classes/MyCookieManager.swift:294:44: error: cannot call value of non-function type 'String?'
                            domain = domainUrl.host()
                                               ^   ~~

    /Users/mobix/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_inappwebview-5.5.0+2/ios/
    Classes/Types/URLCredential.swift:14:25: warning: comparing non-optional value of type '[Any]' to
    'nil' always returns true
            if certificates != nil {
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements
    use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in
    target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

the package i'm using is `youtube_player_flutter: ^8.0.0`. the message indicates to in app web view.

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                configuration.ignoresViewportScaleLimits = options.ignoresViewportScaleLimits
                
                var dataDetectorTypes = WKDataDetectorTypes.init(rawValue: 0)
                for type in options.dataDetectorTypes {
                    let dataDetectorType = Util.getDataDetectorType(type: type)
                    dataDetectorTypes = WKDataDetectorTypes(rawValue: dataDetectorTypes.rawValue | dataDetectorType.rawValue)
                }
                configuration.dataDetectorTypes = dataDetectorTypes
                
                configuration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = options.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture ? .all : []
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
                configuration.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = options.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture
            }
```

and in app web view options

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                realOptions["mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture"] = configuration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback == .all
                realOptions["ignoresViewportScaleLimits"] = configuration.ignoresViewportScaleLimits
                realOptions["dataDetectorTypes"] = Util.getDataDetectorTypeString(type: configuration.dataDetectorTypes)
            } else {
                realOptions["mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture"] = configuration.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction
            }
```

i uncommented the `platform: ios, '9.0'` and replace at the end with

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
    end
  end
end
```

replacing these worked the other error (which is not included in this question) but it doesn't seem to work for these. how can i fix this? i haven't used xcode before so.

my flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H15 darwin-x64, locale en-ET)
    • Flutter version 2.5.3 at /Users/mobix/Development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 18116933e7 (1 year ago), 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700
    • Engine revision d3ea636dc5
    • Dart version 2.14.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/mobix/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.72.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.50.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • iPhone 12 Pro Max (mobile) • 63C29DC5-CD5A-411A-9BAA-C55FA3ED65B3 • ios            •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-4 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)               • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome
      106.0.5249.119

• No issues found!
```

thanks in advance

Comment: same for me i am working on xcode 13 so youtube_player_iframe is working for me

Answer (score 7):

I'm facing this issue since last 2 days.

You don't need to download the X-code-14 version.

just open X-code and run the project it's showing an error then click on the
error and tap fix.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot have update the Xcode just replace every part of code inside ios/Classes/MyCookieManager.swift:

```
if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
  domain = domainUrl.host()
} else {
  domain = domainUrl.host
}
```

with

```
domain = domainUrl.host
```

Comment: but u can just tap on the error and tap on fix it will also work

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update your xcode version to 14 and that's all :)

https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/1369

Here is the reference.

Comment: my mac is outdated. i am using macbook pro mid 2012. so i can't use xcode 14

Comment: Then you have to use lower version which matches your xcode and flutter versions

Comment: yes i'm using the package to be compatible with my versions. but not working

Comment: @MohammedBekele you can use youtube_player_iframe framwork